# EOS R backup solution for SDXC cards

Tags: backup

I have Canon EOS R which use SDXC cards, what is easier solution and light weight for do backup during travel?

I have 2 cards SANDISK SDXC EXTREME PRO 128GB and just in case would like to do additional backups of my cards to not lost all photo/video recorded during traveling for few weeks.

Comment: Suggested duplicate is hopelessly out of date.

Comment: Voting to remain open. The linked "dupe" had good advice for a very specific situation...in 2010...

Answer (score 0):

The [Gnarbox 2.0 SSD](https://www.gnarbox.com/products/gnarbox-2-0-ssd) seems to best the easiest, lightest-weight, and most convenient computer-free solution for backing up — and even editing and organizing (via tablet or smartphone apps) — collected images during travel. It has a built-in SD card slot (supporting SDXC), and a removable battery. The device is charged via USB-C.

The only inconvenient thing about the device is the price, which is $500 for the 256 GB version, up to $900 for the 1 TB version.

Comment: That's a lot for a device that can hold only a few cards of data (OP has 128G cards).  Less costly option: Buy and label cards in pairs (1A/1B, 2A/2B, etc).  Use one card to take new photos (A), copy to the other card (B) using a dual card reader and smartphone.  Can also upload to cloud storage if internet is available.

Comment: @xiota I don't disagree that it's expensive if considered only as mass storage. But when considered as part of a tablet or smartphone-based system for quick culling and editing of lots of images, its value proposition begins to shift. In the context of convenience and speed of transfer, it is vastly more convenient and faster than trying to use a smartphone and dual card reader to try to perform file management (which likely will happen at lower data transfer rates). As far as uploading to cloud storage if internet is available... 10s or 100s of GB is painful for most public wifi connections

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to buy a bunch of SD cards, and then change them daily (or even multiple times per day). That way, if you lose a card or it is corrupt, you only lose a limited amount of pictures.

This solution is fairly cheap and does not require additional devices.
The downside is that you still only have one copy of your images.

There are several portable SD backup devices available but they are quite expendable and unless such a device is used together with the multiple cards solution, you don't really gain anything, as you would just be offloading images to another device.
This device could also become corrupt or lost.
But if you keep the daily SD card in one place and the device in another place you have doubled your chances of having a copy of your images, even if either cards or device is lost.

The EOS R allows you to transfer images to a smartphone or tablet, via the Canon Connect App. Even RAW files can be moved that way. This will allow you to transfer images to your smartphone/tablet and then transfer from there to e.g. Dropbox or Google Drive.
This solution takes time and requires both Internet connection AND a good data plan.

Personally I travel with MANY small SD cards and switch them often. The used cards are then stored in my suitcase back at the hotel.

Answer (score 0):

Get an OTG cable (under $10) and back them up to your phone or a tablet. For extra measures, you can then copy them to a USB stick as well.

I did this for a photo trip to Cuba a few years ago, download the days shots from the camera to a tablet at the end of the day. Then copy from tablet to USB stick so I had 2 copies before I reused the card.